# Is there a standard procedure for connections in iOS when connection type is changed?

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi, network-connection, 3g-network

Suppose that:

- You are connected to Internet over 3G
- You are constantly connected to a server over tcp (like http) and you are retrieving continuous data (like audio or video).
- You enter into a WIFI enabled area which you have auto-connection enabled (remembered network); so iPhone automatically connects to WIFI in the background.

In this case, "as I have inspected" connection that was active through 3G is NOT interrupted. I can handle this situation by manually cutting connection and reconnecting again. (which will use WIFI this time)

However, this is only what I currently inspected and I am not sure if this happens on all OS versions and iOS devices.

Do you know if Apple has a procedure for this scenario? Scenario: Strict rules defined for what iOS does to active connections when connection type is changed from 3G to WIFI or from WIFI to 3G?